# Codeigniter distinct city values using join command

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get **post_id** from **table_1** where **User_id=5** (it's **65**), then I want to get **city name** from **table_2** where **post_id=65** and distinct the city values. I use codeigniter. Could you please check my code below and help me to find the mistake:

```
 public function get_city_list($user_id) {

$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('table_2.city');
$this->db->from('table_2');
$this->db->where('table_2.post_id=table_1.post_id');
$this->db->join('table_1','table_1.user_id = $user_id');
$query = $this->db->get();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('table_2.city');
$this->db->from('table_1');
$this->db->where('table_1.user_id',$user_id);
$this->db->join('table_2','table_1.post_id=table_2.post_id');
$this->db->get();
```

This will do your job;
and don't start writing complex queries at once. start from simpler. 
Read well , write well

And if you want distinct city, try this

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->get('table_2');
```